# Recurrence relation tree method tight bound

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory, recurrence

I am trying to find the asymptotic tight bound for this recurrence:
T(n) = T(n/2)+T(2n/4)+n

I am utilizing the recursive tree method to do so, but I am lost towards the end and would appreciate any guidance.

T(n/2) = T(n/4)+T(n/4)+n/2

T(2n/4) = T(n/2) so it's also T(n/4)+T(n/4)+n/2

T(n/4) = T(n/8)+T(n/8)+n/4

tree:

n

T(n/2) and T(2n/4)

T(n/4) and T(n/4) and T(n/4) and T(n/4)

until T(1) for all of them

At level 1, there is 1 recurrence. At level 2, there is 1 recurrence.
The cost at the root is n.
The cost at level 1 is n.
The cost at level 2 is n.

I know the depth = n/(2^k) = 1 so k = logbase2(n).

However, I am confused about what to do after this. How would I continue going about this problem to find its tight bound?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have all of the pieces, it's just about understanding the recursion-tree method. To find the total cost, you sum the costs of each node (subproblem) across each level of the tree to get per-level costs, then sum the per-level costs to get the total cost.

You've found that the cost at each level is always `n`, since the number of nodes at depth `i`, for `i` in `0, 1, ... k` is `2^i`. At depth `i`, the cost of each node is `n/(2^i) * T(1)` as you say. So, since `k = log2(n) - 1` is the maximum depth, we get a sum over `i` in `0, 1, ... log2(n) - 1` of `n`.

This gives a total of `(n log2 n) * T(1)`, and since `T(1)` is a constant in `ϴ(1)`, we get `T(n) ∈ ϴ(n log2 n)`. This is usually written as `ϴ (n log n)` without specifying a base, since `log2 x ~ log10 x ~ ln x` are separated by a constant multiple, and asymptotically equivalent to any other logarithm with a base greater than 1.